# Xerox Phaser 6280D horizontal line every 3 inches

Tags: laser-printer

I have been having this issue with my printer for the past 6 months or so. With each page I print, there are horizontal black lines every 3 inches as well as a blueish vertical line / marking down the left side. I have removed and cleaned the ink cartridges with no luck.

I have attached a scanned image below of what I am trying to describe. Look closely!

[image: img]

Comment: Have you tried cleaning up the rollers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be looking for a roller that's about 0.955 inches in diameter, since that's what will give you a line every 3 inches.

You may also need to face up to printers (especially fussy color ones) not living forever, or at least not without extensive replacement parts that may come to exceed the cost of a new printer. And I say that as a guy that runs a bunch of LaserJet 4000's (not color, not very fussy, and cheaper per page than anything new, last I ran the numbers. But some of them die anyway, and then I pick their carcasses for the others.)